# Trying to get KO99.exe running on a new computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtualbox, compatibility

I cannot get KO99.exe (either restored from an archive or downloaded from the source: http://retrospec.sgn.net/users/rjordan/klass/) to run on my new(er) computer. Every time I run it, it asks if I want to run in fullscreen. No matter what I say, it crashes with a second or two.

Windows supplies this information:

- `Problem Event Name:  BEX`
- `Application Name:  KO99.exe`
- `Application Version:   0.0.0.0`
- `Application Timestamp: 3f9b8a55`
- `Fault Module Name: StackHash_0a9e`
- `Fault Module Version:  0.0.0.0`
- `Fault Module Timestamp:    00000000`
- `Exception Offset:  0691bb60`
- `Exception Code:    c0000005`
- `Exception Data:    00000008`
- `OS Version:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1`
- `Locale ID: 1033`

I'm running Windows 7 x64 (fully updated) on a custom built PC. No other application fails this way consistently on me.

Thinking it was a problem with Windows 7, I tried it on clean installs of Windows 98, 2000, XP and under Wine under Ubuntu running in the latest VirtualBox. It failed on all of them in a similar way: It loads, asks the fullscreen question, then dies regardless of the answer.

Is there a way I can either debug the application to get it to work, or find out what kind of system I need to get to run it successfully?

Comment: under Windows 8 it works for me.

Comment: So it should work on this PC too; I need to know how to find out what the problem is with this machine.